# Deploy application in payara micro docker image from shell script

Tags: docker, shell, maven, payara, payara-micro

I try to run a payara/micro docker image and deploy my application (war file) from the maven target directory.

I use this image:
https://hub.docker.com/r/payara/micro

On the page, I'm following the `Run from a mounted volume` section.

My shell script (in the root directory) looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

mvn clean package

docker run --rm \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  -v ~/target:/opt/payara/deployments \
  payara/micro
```

But when I run the script no application is deployed to the payara server. I tried to update the line with `-v $(pwd)/target:/opt/payara/deployments \` without success and a new empty folder with the name `target;C` is created in the root folder alongside the target folder that contains my war file.

I guess my question is; how can I run `payara/micro` container and deploy my `target/myapp.war` file to the server from my shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got no answer yet, I want to add my own solution. I kinda cheated but it worked anyway. I combined my shell script with Dockerfile.

I added this Dockerfile into my project root:

```
FROM payara/micro
COPY target/myapp.war $DEPLOY_DIR
```

Then, I updated my shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

mvn clean package

docker build -t my-image .

docker run -p 8080:8080 my-image
```

Now everything works fine.